# How do I list of devices and ios I could add to my C# Appium framework to have it use a different Ios device and Ios OS each time for each test

Tags: c#, appium, browserstack

I started with the below but it is not working well does anyone have something better?

this is where it will be used for Appium

```
opt.AddAdditionalCapability("device", "iPhone XR");
```

Here is the list code so far.

```
public static void Device()
    {
        List<device> items = new List<device>()
        {
            new Item {device= "iPhone XR" };
            new Item {device = "iPhone 8"};

        foreach (var item in items)
            Console.WriteLine("device {0}", item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to let you know that 1 Appium driver session instance is assigned to 1 session execution and execution on multiple devices in the same Appium session would not be possible.

However, I would request that you use the parallel testing feature in order to test your tests on different devices at once. You can refer to the following link for more information:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/getting-started/c-sharp/nunit/parallelize-tests

Comment: Thank you for the link but it describes someone who would take code and setup tests. I already have a solution with tests is there a way I could take just what I do not have?

Comment: If 1 session ends I should be able to call a new one and not have to keep changing the Device Name and Os.